# Display different data based on name (Django)

Tags: python, django

I'm making an online food delivery website using Django.
I have this table showing each restaurant's name and business hours.
If the user clicks the restaurant's name, I want the new page to display the menu of the restaurant. How do I do this?

Below is my code for models.py

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    hours = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    website = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Menu(models.Model):
    restaurant_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='item')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

Below is my code for menu.html

```
<div class="container">

    <table class="table text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Item</th>
                <th scope="col">Price</th>
                <th scope="col">Add to Cart</th>
            </tr>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td> {{ }} </td>
                <td>$ {{ }}</td>
                <td><button class="btn">Add</button></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    
    path('', customer.views.Index, name='index'),
    path('signup/', customer.views.Signup, name='signup'),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), # login
    path('order/', customer.views.Order, name='order'),
    path('menu/', customer.views.Menus, name='menu'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a ForeignKey relationship between your `Menu` and `Restaurant` models. A restaurant can have multiple menus (possibly lunch menu, dinner menu, desert menu, etc.), but a menu can only belong to one restaurant. That's a Many-to-One relationship between Menu and Restaurant. You could use a one-to-one relationship if only one menu per restaurant but the former is more future proof in my opinion.

Replace `restaurant_name` field in `Menu` model with the following:

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='menus')
```

The `on_delete` option means when a restaurant is deleted, its menu will be deleted also.

`related_name` allows you to query the reverse relationship to get all a restaurant's menus with `restaurant.menus.all()` in views or `restaurant.menus.all` in templates.

Then makemigrations and migrate your database. Be careful with changes like this as it can cause integrity errors.

As for how to access it in your template, that's going to depend on what your views/urls look like. Please post your menu detail view and urls for help with that. I don't know how your url params are structured or whether you're using generic / function-based views.

Some other issues with your models that I noticed:

- Why use the name of the restaurant as the primary key? What if two restaurants in different locations have the same name? You should stick to the default auto-incrementing primary key. If you don't want the primary keys to show up in your URLs create a separate unique SlugField to use in your url params.
- You should use a URLField for the website if you want to store a link for better validation at the form and DB level.
- You'll likely want to make category a ForeignKey as well and split it into its own model. That way you can query all the restaurants of a certain category more easily.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I added my code for urls.

Comment: You need a view to pass the requests to that returns an HttpResponse and renders your template. Typically you would have parameters in your urls that can be used in the view to get the correct objects. You should go over the Django tutorial to grasp the basics of the request-response cycle before continuing.